# Parse JSON to Insert Records into table

Tags: .net, json, parsing

I have a web server which is connected to MS SQL with tables having foreign keys. My client code sends me the records in one big JSON string. My server receives it and I want to parse it so that I can insert records into appropriate tables.

Here is my db schema:

```
Table1   
{      
    INT PID    
    INT CID      
    STRING firstname         
    STRING lastname    
}

TABLE2  
{  
    INT CID  
    INT ORDER  
}
```

TABLE1 has CID as a foreign key.

The sample input JSON would be something like

```
{
TABLE1     
{   
"firstname":"Tony"  

"lastname":"Stark"  
}  
TABLE2  
{  
"ORDER":"1234"  
}  
}
```

What's the best approach for this?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The JSON you are getting from your client is an Input into your system, and you should treat it like that. Never trust your input, so make sure to validate the schema to make sure the JSON is what you expect it to be, and of course you need error handling.

You should use newtonsoft JSON.NET to parse the JSON.

http://james.newtonking.com/json

Here is an example:

```
string json = @"{
 'Name': 'Bad Boys',
 'ReleaseDate': '1995-4-7T00:00:00',
    'Genres': [
    'Action',
    'Comedy'
   ]
 }";

Movie movie = JsonConvert.DeserializeObject<Movie>(json);
```

After you convert JSON to an object, you can persist the object into the DB easily.

If you map your RDBMS tables to objects with Entity Framework or any other ORM you will simplify the storage of the deserialized JSON object.

Since you shouldn't trust your inputs, I would recommend mapping your deserialized input object to your ORM or Table objects manually or you can use smart tools like `Automapper`

http://automapper.org/

Comment: Problem is after deserialization, I should know which table to insert the records into. If I know table name, I should also know related tables to which the records needs to be inserted into. Any approach could you suggest for this?

Comment: Thats a pretty complex piece. I have described two approaches. However, things can get pretty complex. If you expand your question description with a sample JSON file schema and the DB schema it will be easier to answer your question.

Comment: Edited the questions with example. Please let me know a generic approach if any because JSON can have any tables, which are newly created at runtime

Comment: Thanks for the code. However, the JSON you provided is not valid. Can you provide the actual JSON you are getting and then validate it with http://jsonlint.com/